# Notice: attribute_escape is deprecated

Tags: debug

I have WP_DEBUG set to ON to show errors and notices. Of all notices the one that is bothering me is `Notice: attribute_escape is deprecated since version 2.8! Use esc_attr() instead. in /Users/john/Documents/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3467`. I started commenting the code to find which function or statement was generating these notices. To my surprise these notices were thrown by `wp_head()`, `echo get_the_title()` — The core Wordpress functions. I switched the theme to twentyeleven where the problem does not appear at all.

So, I'd like to find out why these core functions are throwing notices in my theme and what can I do to debug, isolate and resolve these?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proves that the problem isn't core:

> I switched the theme to twentyeleven where the problem does not appear at all.

Core functions are not throwing those notices. Your Theme is calling the deprecated function(s) somewhere - perhaps in a filer callback for `the_title`.

Search your Theme files to find the culprit. Start in `functions.php`.

p.s. what Theme are you using?

Comment: bennette Thx for the reply. It is a custom theme, built from scratch. BTW, could echoing get_the_title() without escaping result in such a notice? Meanwhile, I'll start digging the theme to find the culprit.

Comment: "*could echoing get_the_title() without escaping result in such a notice*": **No**; that notice means that, *somewhere, the **Theme is calling `attribute_escape()`***.

Comment: Got it. It was a hook that was calling attribute_escape within the function for removing Private/Protected from post titles. Thx a million for the help.